# Returning an item after completed streaming items in a stream (list) in RxPy

Tags: python

is it possible to switch a stream of list items to emit an item at the completion of `do_action`

for example :

```
def add_hobbies(a_student, hobbies):
    return hobbies.pipe(
        op.do_action(lambda h: add_hobby(a_student, h)),
    )
```

`add_hobbies()` will emit items in hobbies stream. I want at the end of hobbies stream, it emits `a_student`.

I try this but it returns : *'Observable' object is not callable*

```
def add_hobbies(a_student, hobbies):
    return hobbies.pipe(
        op.do_action(lambda h: add_hobby(a_student, h), on_completed=rx.of(a_student)),
    )
```

Many thanks.